# How to restart the macro when changing in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know how to explain the problem, hope you understand

I use the code to force the user to fill out the form in order

The problem I have is 4 combobox

The 1 opens the 3 or 4 by the value of 1

If I change the value of 1, I have to write the value again in 2 to open the 3 or 4

My problem is that he does not constantly check what the value is in 1, only when there is a change in 2

How can I force the 2 to constantly check the value in 1?

That's the code I have

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim lLoc As Long
lLoc = Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex
If lLoc = -1 Then
    Me.ComboBox2.SetFocus
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Else
        ComboBox3.Enabled = True
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "abc" Then
        ComboBox4.Enabled = True
    Else
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the `ComboBox1_Change()` event if you want to trigger code on every change on ComboBox1 values. `ComboBox2_Change()` only triggers if ComboBox2 changes.

Comment: True, but because I want to force the user to fill in order, it does not suit me, is there any other way?

Comment: *"I want to force the user to fill in order"* If ComboBox1 is changed simply reset ComboBox2 to 4, this forces the user to select again if he went one step back. This is a common praxis to force the right order. • A change in ComboBox1 will always only trigger the `ComboBox1_Change()` event.